# How to store lookup values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a collection in db which represents mediafiles. 
And among other info I shoud store format name. I wonder if there best practices to store info like that. Is it better to create new collection for file formats and use link to that collection or to store format name right in file documents as a plain text? What about perfomance and compression? It supposed to be more than a billion documents in db. What would mongo expers suggest in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Embedded documents are the preferred approach.

In your case, it means it is better to store file format in the same collection.

Putting the file format into the separate collection means creating a new file on the disk.

It is a slower option and should be used if your document ( any of them ) exceeds 16 MB in size.

See these links for more information

[6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

and

[How to Program with MongoDB Using the .NET Driver](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/how-to-program-with-mongodb-using-the-net-driver/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One question - why embedded document in my case is preferable to just having text "field"?

Comment: IMO the right way in your case is to make some tests. You can try creating a new collection.  As you probably know in order to join two or more collections, the aggregation framework is used with the lookup operator. 
Perform some CRUD operations and measure the response of MongoDb. 
Try another approach with embedded documents. Repeat CRUD operations. Compare the result. 
Based on that, make a decision.

Comment: Yes, but the my main problem is not perfomance but memory on disk. I wonder if mongo will compress embedded documents opposed to persisting repeating format text every time for every document.

Comment: As you probably know wiredTiger is default storage engine in MongoDb. For every collection, Snappy compression is enabled by default. Similar is with indexes. So called prefix compression is enabled by default. You can change the compression type using following snippet in the mongo shell. db.createCollection( "your collection name", { storageEngine: {
                       wiredTiger: { configString: "blockCompressor=zlib" }}}) Zlib compression is most efficient compression, but more resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some benchmarks and figured out that *in my case* storing "lookup values" as **plaintext** is more efficient in terms of disk space than **embedded document** and than **reference to outstanding collection**. Sorry for poor terminology.